# What is the base class for Tensorflow models that only models inherits from

Tags: tensorflow

I’m working on supporting automatic model detection/logging for Tensorflow models for our Machine learning platform https://iko.ai and I want to know what is the base class for models that only models inherit from? i.e. I’m looking for the class X that passes this condition: If a class Y inherits from class X, Y is a Tensorflow model.

Answer (score 0):

All models inherit from `tf.keras.Model` class

Comment: Does all classes that inherited from `tf.keras.Model` models?

Comment: What about `tensorflow_estimator` ?

Comment: Not all classes inherit from tf.keras.Model - only models

Comment: I am not familiar with tensorflow_estimator

Comment: Thanks, any other way (other than base classes) to differentiate between models and non-models classes?